# Print .pdf filenames from a directory with Boost.regex

Tags: c++, boost

This is my code:

```
path Path = "e:\\Documents\\";
boost::regex reg("(*.pdf)");
for(recursive_directory_iterator it(Path); it != recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
    if(boost::regex_search(it->string(), reg))
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

But I always get and Abort() error in Visual Studio, after running the program, the problem is in this line:

```
boost::regex reg("(*.pdf)");
```

Am I not declaring the regex object good ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.pdf` isn't a regex, it's a glob (for file matching).  You need

```
boost::regex reg("(.*\\.pdf)");
```

- `.`: matches any one character
- `*`: 0 or more of the previous match
- `\\`: to make a single `\` for escaping (ignore the regex meaning of the next character)

Comment: Thank you, I thought it will work just like in linux, now its working good

Comment: It is a standard regex just like when a regex is needed in linux.  In a terminal, at the prompt, you are supposed to give a glob, not a regex.  For grep, the matching argument is a regex, so you type `grep <regex> <file glob>`

Comment: I got confused why you use 2 of "\" there, but I see that is working with one also

Comment: That's because `.` matches any character including an actual `.`.  It will also match filename-pdf, filename+pdf, etc.  If you only want to match filename.pdf, use `\\.`